# Find builds where none of the artifacts have been downloaded using AQL

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

for cleanup purposes I am currently trying to build an AQL query that lists all builds where all respective artifacts have not been downloaded. This is what I have right now:

```
builds.find(
  {
    "created" : {"$before" : "2mo"},
    "name": {"$match":"* master"},
    "module.artifact.item.stat.downloads": {"$eq":null} 
  }
).limit(1000)
```

The problem with this is that I get all builds that include a single artifact with no downloads but others might be downloaded. So I would need to do another query per build to determine the download count of all artifacts.

Is there a way to tell AQL that all artifacts of a build have to match the query?

Answer (score 1):

For your query I think this is the solution:

```
items.find(
    "name" : {"$match" : "*master"}
    "stat.downloads" : {"$eq" : null }
)
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) for more info.

Comment: This will find items that have not been downloaded, I want to find builds where none of its artifacts have been downloaded.